# MySQL Multiple replace

Tags: mysql

I currently have this join in my query

```
LEFT JOIN "db1"."table2" t2 ON t2.uid = CAST(REPLACE(t3.uid, 'text:', '') as bigint)
```

But we have occurrences now where in t3.destination we also have for example 'text2:' to replace. How do I replace more than 1 string value found?

Comment: Let's not assume replace is the only option, please add examples of t3.uid

Comment: examples of a value for t3.uid = 'text:1000' and an example of t2.uid = 1000 hence the requirement to remove 'text:'

Answer (score 1):

If the format of t3.uid is always TEXT:nnnn or nnnn you could

```
substring_index(t3.uid,':',-1)
```

Comment: Thx - great answer